# How to make a lever invulnerable/unbreakable in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanna know how can I make a lever invulnerable so that **lava can't burn it** and a **player can't remove it**.

I tried the following but it didn't work :

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[item=lever,r=10] add iMarker
/entitydata @e[tag=iMarker] {Invulnerable:1}
```

This processes something and no errors are shown but still the lever is burned by lava.

Comment: Lava shouldn't burn levers?

Comment: Well if lava goes on it, the lever disappears.

Comment: That isn't the lever burning (though the raw item will burn), that is the lava "washing" the lever away.

Comment: Well maybe. I wanna avoid this. I know it's possible with ArmorStand so why not lever ? :)

Comment: Because a armor stand is a entity, a lever is a block/item.

Comment: Run a command block clock to constantly replace the lever without dropping anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1: **place signs or simmilar blocks around the lever**. For the lever not to be destroyed by Players give then Adventure mode (`/gamemode @a a`)

Method 2: Use this all-version-usable Command block & Redstone syntax:

[image: SUPER STUFF!!]

Where the lever is at positive X from the Redstone. The right Command block has this command:

> /testforblock ~+2 ~ ~ minecraft:lever

And the left one has this:

> /**fill** ~+7 ~ ~ ~+7 ~ ~ minecraft:lever **N**

Instead of N use the lever rotation value. [List of possible rotations](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever#Block_data):

```
N | Rotation

0: Lever on block bottom points east when off.
1: Lever on block side facing east
2: Lever on block side facing west
3: Lever on block side facing south
4: Lever on block side facing north
5: Lever on block top points south when off.
6: Lever on block top points east when off.
7: Lever on block bottom points south when off.
```

- The lever **can** get destroyed, but immediatley replaced
- I think you can remove the Repeater :-)
- You can have the command blocks **really** far away, it works the samr, just the coordinates will be different.
- You can update this to use the 1.9 Command block stuff
- It's easy-to-build! Go do it yourself!

Comment: It works but it's not really convenient as I don't have much space and more than one lever to be "invulnerable". Is this the only way to process ? (As it isn't really an answer to my question)

Comment: @FromBabylon I don't know any non-command block way of saving a lever in rising lava :D

Comment: @FromBabylon WAIT! I know! Added it to the answer: surround the lever with see-through blocks, eg. signs!

Comment: I already done that but it's not pretty :P Thanks

Comment: @FromBabylon awwwwwwww I won't get the check mark :D

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to come with a better solution. I've already play games with block that can't be destructed by players so there should be a way. If there is not, then your answer is the best solution and I will mark it

Comment: @FromBabylon you can avoid destroying by Players - or by the Command block way, or by putting all Players into Adventure mode - `/gamemode @a 2`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to make an invunruble lever, is to get the coordinates of the lever and enter this command:

> /setblock x y z minecraft:lever

on a repeat Command block.

That would work best when you have a map where you want to have them break stuff other then the lever. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to */setblock x y z lever [name=Unbreakable]* on a repeating command block and on another repeating command block */clear @a lever [name=Unbreakable]*(the name is so that you can clear it but not have to worry about clearing other levers.